# Multiple Image Buttons

Tags: android, imagebutton

I created an activity on android studio and I have put there something like 20 `ImageButton`s. I want to use it as on each click on an image it will move to a new activity. All of the Image Buttons are working on the same principle, my app is a game, and each image represents a level. I want to build one function that will be used on all buttons and will move the user to a new activity according to the data(the properties of the image button) and use that data on the new activity. Every level has its own activity and the main activity is the menu of the game.

Below is my code:

```
public ImageButton beatsCall; public void Beats(){ beatsCall=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.beats); beatsCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent toy = new Intent(Levels.this,Beats.class); startActivity(toy); } }); }
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: `public ImageButton levelCall;


    public void CallLevel(){
        levelCall=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.level1);
        levelCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toy = new Intent(Levels.this,Level1.class);
                startActivity(toy);
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Can you edit the question and add this as code in your original question. This improves readability and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more information and code. However, you may want to try set a distinct `onClickListener` and then set all the imageButtons to that listener that will perform an action depending on the button clicked. For example, say you have 4 imageButtons and you want to perform a different action (in your case, start a new activity) for each different button click.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                //Start activity 1 here, for example
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity1.class);
                String message = v.getId().toString;
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.textView2:
                //Start activity 2 here
                break;
            case R.id.textView3:
                //Start activity 3 here
                break;
            case R.id.textView4:
                //Start activity 4 here
        }

    }
};

button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
button4.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

This is assuming you have the imageButtons set up in your layout file and you have them initialized in your activity.

In your new activity, you can get the message as such:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
if (some condition with message){
      do something
}
```

You may also check out this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for further information regarding intents.

Comment: I think it can help. But I also need to use the data in the new activity, I mean I want to have one activity that will change its appearance according to which ImageButton sent me to it.

Comment: You can use an extra `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);` to send data to your next activity and based on the data, you may call different fragments or do something in your new activity.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include sending data. You can customize the data depending on which button sent it and use it in your new Activity. Does this help?

Comment: Let us know if there are any issues and if this helps, do mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I have a problam with the line:

`String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`


It doesn't recognize the EXTRA_MESSAGE even when I imported it. Do you know what is the problam?

Comment: Did you create `EXTRA_MESSAGE` in your mainActivity? As in `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);`? Maybe the first activity is named something else in your app, try that name when you call `EXTRA_MESSAGE` in your second activity as in `String message = intent.getStringExtra(YourFirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`

Comment: That's how I wrote and it didn't recognize the EXTRA_MESSAGE in the new activity

Comment: Do you know why is it happening?

Comment: You need to add EXTRA_MESSAGE as a public key in the first activity. For example, before onCreate in your first Activity, add this: `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";` so that it is accessible by the second activity.

Comment: If it works, do upvote and select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  In your xml make your images clickable and give them ID's like this...

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level_1_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
```

Then call a function like this in your Activity's onCreate

```
private void setupButtons() {
    findViewById(R.id.level_1_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), LevelOne.class));
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.level_2_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), LevelTwo.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a tag via android:tag to each of your views and then use your single listener to switch on the view's tag to branch the behavior you want.